# Lucene net IndexWriter after UpdateDocument doubles the size of index even with optimize?

Tags: indexing, lucene.net, lucene

I'm creating the index in a normal way:

```
var directory = FSDirectory.Open(...);
var analyzer = ...

var indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
indexWriter.SetWriteLockTimeout(30000);

indexWriter.AddDocument(doc1);
indexWriter.AddDocument(doc2);
indexWriter.AddDocument(...);

indexWriter.Commit();
indexWriter.Optimize();
indexWriter.Close();
```

This creates an index of 5.8mb

Now I need to update 2 documents exactly..with 1 word added in each of them...so the size of index should be increased either by a very small amount or none at all:

```
var indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, false, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
indexWriter.SetWriteLockTimeout(30000);

indexWriter.UpdateDocument(doc1);
indexWriter.UpdateDocument(doc2);

indexWriter.Commit();
**indexWriter.Optimize();**
indexWriter.Close();
```

This operation DOUBLES the size of index in a way that it leaves **_0.cfs** file of the size the index was at previously **5.8mb**...and creates a whole new index of the same size in _2.xxx files...so for a two document with one word changes, it doubles it!

It also continues doing this if I repeat the operation...so it just doubles it forever.

My thoughts were that **Optimize** call should optimize it and not cause things like these?

How do I stop it from doubling my index?

Thnx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually caused by having IndexReaders/IndexSearchers opened on the index while you optimize. IndexReaders see a snapshot of the Index when they were opened so they keep a lock on the files and the IndexWriter cannot remove them when its closed.

After optmize, you should refresh IndexReaders/IndexSearchers either by re-creating them or by using the Reopen() method on IndexReader. Once the IndexReaders/IndexSearchers are refreshed, if you create an IndexWriter and Close it immediately, you should see the files disapear.

That being said, if you decide to optimize live indexes (which you should only do when you delete lots of documents), you should always expect the Index to temporarily grow 3X it's "normal" size.

Comment: Thnx, that did it! I wrapped IndexSearcher in c# using statement which disposes of index after searching not to leave it hanging, and that did the trick!

Btw. do you know would it be smarter to cache the IndexSearcher for performanse?

Also if I do cache it, is there a way to force kill of all searchers at night for example (my indexing is done once a day at night by a separate application when almost no one is using the searcher web application)?

Comment: yes you should be trying to keep the Searcher opened as long as possible since internally lucene caches informations in the underlying IndexReader, which help with performances. What I usually do is have a Manager that keeps my IndexSearcher instances, usually 1 per index. When I'm about to close my IndexWriter, I first close the IndexSearchers using the Manager, and then close the IndexWriter afterward.

Comment: I have done optimize on my index. It grew from 370 to 826 GB in size, but files are for a single segment now and it doesnt shrink in size after trying your advice. Any more advice you can give me? Thanks.